# Lock and unlock orientation in phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I want to enable and disable changes in orientation using phonegap.

For android there is the java call,

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

but I was looking for something that was cross-platform, there is also the config.xml

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
```

but this is a global setting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

for cross platform in android add this line for portrait mode

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

and this one is for landscape

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

just after this line

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in your onCreate method,this solution is for android as i have not worked in ios i can  not help you on it.